# Where will String::from("") be allocated in a match arm?

Tags: rust, embedded

I am still very new to rust, coming from a C embedded world.

If i have a piece of code like this:

```
    match self {
        Command::AT => String::from("AT"),
        Command::GetManufacturerId => String::from("AT+CGMI"),
        Command::GetModelId => String::from("AT+CGMM"),
        Command::GetFWVersion => String::from("AT+CGMR"),
        Command::GetSerialNum => String::from("AT+CGSN"),
        Command::GetId => String::from("ATI9"),
        Command::SetGreetingText { ref enable, ref text } => {
          if *enable {
            if text.len() > 49 {
              // TODO: Error!
            }
            write!(buffer, "AT+CSGT={},{}", *enable as u8, text).unwrap();
          } else {
            write!(buffer, "AT+CSGT={}", *enable as u8).unwrap();
          }
          buffer
        },
        Command::GetGreetingText => String::from("AT+CSGT?"),
        Command::Store => String::from("AT&W0"),
        Command::ResetDefault => String::from("ATZ0"),
        Command::ResetFactory => String::from("AT+UFACTORY"),
        Command::SetDTR { ref value } => {
          write!(buffer, "AT&D{}", *value as u8).unwrap();
          buffer
        },
        Command::SetDSR { ref value } => {
          write!(buffer, "AT&S{}", *value as u8).unwrap();
          buffer
        },
        Command::SetEcho { ref enable } => {
          write!(buffer, "ATE{}", *enable as u8).unwrap();
          buffer
        },
        Command::GetEcho => String::from("ATE?"),
        Command::SetEscape { ref esc_char } => {
          write!(buffer, "ATS2={}", esc_char).unwrap();
          buffer
        },
        Command::GetEscape => String::from("ATS2?"),
        Command::SetTermination { ref line_term } => {
          write!(buffer, "ATS3={}", line_term).unwrap();
          buffer
        }    
    }
```

How does it work in Rust? Will all these match arms evaluate immediately, or will only the one matching create a mutable copy on the stack? And also, will all the string literals withing my `String::from("")` be allocated in `.rodata`?

Is there a better way of doing what i am trying to do here? Essentially i want to return a string literal, with replaced parameters (the write! macro bits)?

Best regards

Comment: String is allocated, it's not clear what you ask.

Comment: Depending on how hot this function is, you might see a performance improvement from returning a [`Cow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 4):

Only the matching arm will be evaluated. The non matching arms have no cost apart the size of the program.

In the general case, it's not even possible to evaluate other arms, as they depend on data read using destructuring of the pattern.

As for your second question, the location in a program where literals are stored isn't commonly named rodata, and it's neither specified nor guaranteed (it's usually deduplicated but that's just optimization).

Comment: wouldn't the string content be allocated in the heap ? `String::from(&str)` basically copies the str bytes into a new `Vec` and its content is heap allocated.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev This only happens when the arm is matching

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Ohh yea, sorry. If you are referring to my "will only the one matching create a mutable copy on the stack", i of course meant the heap, not stack.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Okay, thank you for your clarification!

So in general, is my approach to this okay, or is there another way of doing this that would be smarter, faster or better optimized?

I have a very large match clause, where the snippet in OP, is just a small part of it.

Comment: @smilykoch What you do seems efficient. Maintainability might be another problem though. I would probably have a more compact enum, maybe with some composite variants `GetField(String), SetField(String)` but you need to see more to determine the proper strategy.